# iMovie Crashes Part-way Through Export

Tags: macbook, imovie

I have an 8 minute iMovie 09 movie, which I am trying to export. Regardless of resolution, or normal export vs. Quicktime export, it crashes every time, nearly at the end. I have exported the movie earlier today, which worked.

I found the crash report logs, here's one of them in case it helps:

http://pastebin.com/ikyR37Ec

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000ffffffbf
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
```

I urgently have to get this done in less than half an hour, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Computer is a white MacBook 7,1.